# Fast Parallel Patch Extraction using CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I'm currently looking for a parallel algorithm to extract patches from an image volume. The two inputs are a 3D volume (e.g. 320x320x20) and some kind of feature map (same dimensions as volume) containing labels 0 and 1.

Depending on some evaluation of the 3D neighborhood around each voxel and its value inside the feature map, a patch with the size of that neighborhood should be extracted and stored into global memory.

The kernel call should look something like this:

```
int image_volume = new int[320][320][20];
... fill image_volume
int label_volume = new int[320][320][20];
... fill label_volume
int patch_matrix = new int[?][?];

__global__ parallel_patch_extraction(image_volume, label_volume, patch_matrix)
{
    if((label_volume[global_thread_id] == 1) && (...evaluation is true inside neighborhood...))
    {
        ... store patch in global memory
    }
}
```

Since I don't know before how many potential patches can be extracted, I would need to dynamically allocate or reallocate the data buffer on the GPU where the patches are written to.

Is this possible in CUDA, and if not, is there a different possibility to achieve parallel patch extraction, for example split the work into two kernels, where the first one only evaluates the neighborhood and the second one is used for extracting the patches.